# Canvas Element - Rotation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, multiplayer

I've multiple canvas elements, each one work on his own. I would like to use these to create a multiplayer. It works perfectly, but now I would like to rotate single  canvas elements (180 degree). I tried the getContext('2d') method but it only helps me for a single obeject on the canvas. But what I would like to do is to rotate the WHOLE canvas.

Does someone know how I can do this?

Feilx

Comment: I'm unclear. Are you trying to rotate individual elements on the canvas, or rotate the entire canvas containing all elements, or are you trying to rotate both individual elements & the whole canvas at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could utilize [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)  and [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) methods for that purpose, the following example illustrates it:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var angleInput = document.getElementById("angleInput");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var angleInDegrees=0;
drawRotated(ctx,angleInDegrees);

document.getElementById("clockwiseButton").addEventListener('click',function(){
 angleInDegrees+=parseInt(angleInput.value);
 drawRotated(ctx,angleInDegrees);
});

document.getElementById("counterclockwiseButton").addEventListener('click',function(){
 angleInDegrees-=parseInt(angleInput.value);
 drawRotated(ctx,angleInDegrees);
});



function drawRotated(ctx,degrees){
 var canvasWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvasWidth/2,canvasHeight/2); // Move registration point to the center of the canvas
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180); // Rotate
    drawObjects(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
}



function drawObjects(ctx)
{
   //draw triangle
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(200,150);
   ctx.lineTo(150,200);
   ctx.lineTo(250,200);
   ctx.fill();

   //draw circle
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(350,75,50,0,Math.PI*2,false); 
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();

   //draw rectangle
   ctx.fillRect(50,50,150,50);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button id="clockwiseButton">Rotate right</button>
   <button id="counterclockwiseButton">Rotate left</button>
   <input id="angleInput" value="45"></input>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/Lxuau9nt/)